# Rotacionar nomes no eixo x

Tags: r

Boa tarde como faço para plotar o gráfico gerado pelo código abaixo de tal forma que o nome dos tratamentos V10RC4, V15RC3, V20RC2 e V25RC1 apareçam na diagonal?

```
barplot(1:4, names.arg = c("V10RC4","V15RC3", "V20RC2", "V25RC1"), las=2)
```

O comando las=2 exibe os tratamentos na vertical. Existe algum outro comando que eu possa usar?

Answer (score 4):

O truque é não plotar o eixo em questão, neste caso o eixo dos `x` com `xaxt = "n"` e depois usar o valor de retorno do `barplot` para anotar o eixo com `text`. Repare no argumento `par('usr')[3]`, é ele que dá a posição correta de `labels`. O ângulo é dado por `srt = 45`.

```
labels <- c("V10RC4","V15RC3", "V20RC2", "V25RC1")
bp <- barplot(1:4, xaxt = "n", axisnames = FALSE)
text(bp, par('usr')[3], labels = labels, 
     srt = 45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex = 0.9)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edição.**

Para responder ao pedido de ter letras em cima das barras, em comentário, usa-se mais uma vez a função `text` com o valor de retorno `bp` acima como coordenadas do eixo dos `x`.

A parte mais complicada é ter cuidado com o comprimento do eixo dos `y`. Para o aumentar o suficiente para se conseguirem ver todas as letras, uso a função `strheight`. Esta função dá um valor aproximado da altura da letra 'M'. Abaixo o código duplica esse valor e soma-lhe o máximo dos valores das barras.

```
bp <- barplot(dados$values, xaxt = "n", axisnames = FALSE,
              ylim = c(0, max(dados$values) + 2*strheight('M')))
text(bp, dados$values, labels = LETTERS[1:nrow(dados)], pos = 3)
text(bp, par('usr')[3], labels = dados$labels, 
     srt = 45, adj = c(1.1, 1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex = 0.9)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código para criar os dados.**

```
set.seed(123)
values <- sample(10, 4, TRUE)
labels <- c("V10RC4","V15RC3", "V20RC2", "V25RC1")
dados <- data.frame(values, labels)
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo. Rui você sabe como faço para inserir letras em cima das barras do gráfico?

Comment: @VitorHugo Feito, veja a edição.

Comment: O que eu modifico no código para inserir apenas uma letra em uma única barra. Por exemplo inserir a letra A na barra referente a V25C1 e as demais deixar sem letras?

Comment: @VitorHugo tente `labels = c('A', rep('', nrow(dados) - 1))`. Ou seja, um vetor de espaços e letras, com espaços onde não quer nada.